# Handling race conditions when figuring out when scripts on multiple machines have finished

Tags: python, race-condition

I will be having a script running on separate machines and I need to figure out when all instances are finished so I can run one final function (which will be run by the last script that finishes).

Most of the time they would start and end at separate times, but I'd like to be able to handle any case where multiple finish at the same time. I've been using threading to test and I'm not able to figure out a robust solution. Here's the ideas I had:

With attempting to append to file:
Similar code to below where I'm adding a unique UTF8 character to a file. When the number of characters matches the threads and the character is the same as the current one, it means the last function has run. Unfortunately the last function can read the file before others have finished writing.

With attempting to rename (apparently a file can be renamed multiple times):

```
def func(file_format, num_threads):
    for index in xrange(num_threads):
        try:
            os.rename(file_format.format(index), file_format.format(index + 1))
            print str(index) + '\n'
            break
        except WindowsError:
            pass

file_format = 'W:/tmp/peter/race_condition_test/unique_id.{}'
num_threads = 6
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(file_format.format(0), 'w') as f:
        pass
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(target=partial(func, file_format, 6))
        t.start()
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

With checking the folder for written files:

```
def func(iteration, folder, file_name, num_threads):
    path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
    with open(path.format(iteration), 'w') as f:
        pass
    print str(os.listdir(folder)) + '\n'

num_threads = 6
folder = 'W:/tmp/peter/race_condition_test'
file_name = 'unique_id.{}'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(target=partial(func, i, folder, file_name, num_threads))
        t.start()
```

Output:

```
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
['unique_id.4', 'unique_id.2', 'unique_id.3', 'unique_id.0', 'unique_id.5', 'unique_id.1']
```

Running the final code only once is fairly important, as it's using the API of an external program to update something. Wouldn't be the end of the world if I had to use the final method with the chance of running more than once, but are there any other good ways to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(iteration, folder, file_name):
    path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)
    with open(path.format(iteration), 'w') as f:
        pass
    print str(os.listdir(folder)) + '\n'

num_threads = 6
folder = 'W:/tmp/peter/race_condition_test'
file_name = 'unique_id.{}'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_threads):
        t = Thread(target=partial(func, i, folder, file_name))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()    # you need to join to know when they all finish
```

Or you can use a ThreadPool in multiprocessing (not sure why its hidden in the Multiprocess class and not in the Thread class, but it's there.

Comment: Cheers but I'm not able to join them as different machines are running them - I'm only using threading locally to simulate the race conditions.

Comment: Oh I see, it's not so much a threading issue as a distributed issue. What are you using to distribute the work? Something like https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html ? Typically you need a JobMaster (socket server usually), something to input tasks and as many workers as you want. the JobMaster will know when all tasks are finished and can do what you want at the end. Are you just going to all the different worker machines and "python runscript.py" on each machine and now have no way to coordinate when they're all done?

Comment: So I'm actually using this with Deadline, which sends 3D render jobs to a render farm. The scenes are split into multiple jobs, and the jobs have multiple tasks. You can define a script to run on job finish, but as I'm splitting scenes up, there's no way of getting when the scene has finished, so I'm relying on counting the number of times the script has been run.

Comment: I haven't used Deadline, but what kind of script can you run? You can basically make a socket server/http server on your end. At the end of all your scene jobs, run a script to either connect to your socket server or your http server, basically http GET /jobID (or something) and have your server figure out what jobs are done or arent. When they're all done, you can decide what to do next. It would probably be best to contact Deadline and ask them since this is probably something another customer has had to do also. Gluck.

Comment: In a way that's a good suggestion, but I have limited permissions (not in IT), and this will be happening hundreds of times per day, and potentially even long after I leave, so requiring a certain pc to be running as a server (along with the extra code to figure out what relates to which job) could end up a little messy haha. The purpose of the script is basically to hook into an API to update the render progress of the current scene so the department leads can know when a shot needs reviewing. It's not super important so I don't wanna go overboard, just would be nice if there was a simple way

Comment: In response to your suggestion to contact Deadline, we're doing it a bit differently than what is standard, normally a scene isn't split into multiple jobs. The post job script is literally only meant to run after a job, I'm grouping them though and there's no way for deadline to know they've been submitted as part of the same batch :P